# TYPO3 extension repository truncate query

Tags: php, sql, typo3, extbase

I need to clear (TRUNCATE) a database table through the repository of my TYPO3 extension. I already have various working SELECT queries. They look like this:

```
public function getUsergroups() {

    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setReturnRawQueryResult(TRUE);

    $query->statement('SELECT * FROM fe_groups WHERE hidden=0 AND deleted=0');

    $result = $query->execute();

    return $result;
}
```

This works.

Then there is the function for clearing the database table, it looks like this:

```
public function updateProductPermissions($submitArray) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setReturnRawQueryResult(TRUE);

    $query->statement('TRUNCATE TABLE tx_chiliproducts_domain_model_permission')->execute();

    return true;
}
```

When this function gets executed, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object
>   in
>   /srv/globalroot/typo3_src-6.1.1/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Database/DatabaseConnection.php
>   on line 1029

What's the difference between executing a SELECT and executing a TRUNCATE statement? Why does one work and the other does not?

Comment: I just tried out a function for inserting new data into the table. It results in the same error as the TRUNCATE function. Could it be that "write" statements (TRUNCATE, INSERT) have to be handled differently than "read" (SELECT) statements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if you can truncate through the extbase persistence layer. If you want to make your life easy, just use the normal TYPO3 CMS database class:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_TRUNCATEquery('table');
```

Keep in mind that extbase might not know about this truncate and that it might still have some objects in the cache.

The API way would be to call `$repository->removeAll()`.

Comment: The `removeAll()` method works only on the current repository. If *tx_chiliproducts_domain_model_permission* is the table for the current repository then it will work otherwise not.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `removeAll()`! Basically, this works just fine since I am in the correct repository. But unlike a _truncate_ statement, this function does not reset the UIDs. After some time, I'm afraid that this will get quite ugly with huge UID values. Is there no equivalent to a _truncate_ statement?

Comment: Not the best idea but it might be work:
First use `removeAll()` to remove the content from the table and after that, use TYPO3s database API method `exec_TRUNCATEquery()` to reset the uids.

Beside that, you can file a feature request at http://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/issues to get it build  in.

Comment: Thanks Stefano, the combination of both commands works for me!

Comment: One last thing - the order is important: first `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_TRUNCATEquery('tx_chiliproducts_domain_model_permission');`, then `$this->removeAll();`. When I tried it the other way around, I experienced problems where only the first few entries were written into the database.

Comment: Calling removeAll() and then TRUNCATE makes no sens. If you TRUNCATE do not use removeAll(). removeAll()  just set deleted=1 for every entry. So this makes no sens, because your are TRUNCATE the table shortly after anyway. It would add some overhead.

Comment: @FabianThommen The `removeAll()` removes any stale object runtime caches in extbase. From a DB point of view, this makes no difference, but it can help you a lot in your current request.